# MSdeploy.exe how to use special character in setparam value

Tags: iis, webdeploy, msdeploy

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"
```

We would like to use `-setParam:"TestParam"="hello&1"`, but PowerShell sees the `&` character as the call operator instead of a literal. How can we change this to use the & as literal in the setparam value?

Comment: Have you tried the escape character?

Comment: Hello @JokiesDing, yes, that doesn't work.